# sending data from java to built website

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, sockets

i seem to have reached a impass with my code, im trying to make a java server that maintains my website. My problem is getting data from my java to my website.

this is my ajax im suing to to send stuff to my java, i sends, but i dont know how to send data to my success

```
        function doAjax()
       {
//            var valstring = JSON.stringify(values);
//            var user = {json:valstring};
         var data=$("#with").val()+":"+$("#date").val()+":"+$("#where").val();
               $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
                       data: data,
                      url: "http://localhost:55556",

                      cache: false,
                      success: function(result)
                      {     
                        alert("sent");
                   alert(result.toString());

                      },
                      failure: function()
                      {
                              alert('An Error has occured, please try again.');
                      }
              });
       }
});
```

my java server on the other hand looks like so

```
while(//connection)
{
     clientSocket = AcceptConnection();
       inp =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (clientSocket.getInputStream()));  
      //using inp to get data
      //other tedious code
}
```

but now if i use .getOutputStream() it doesn't do anything, any of u guys have a solution?

I would honestly appreciate suggestions or any **knowledge** on how to get that **success** **function** to work or even an **alternative**. just keep in mind that this website is already built, not outputted via socket

Answer (score 0):

A simple socket server doesn't understand the HTTP protocol.  Shouldn't this be obvious?  Either install a Java webserver, like Tomcat, or find a HTTP Server library to use to build your own.   My suggestion would be to install Tomcat (or another servlet container), and learn  how to use JSP and Servlets.  Writing your own webserver will be a total waste of time unless you are doing it to put on an embedded device, which I doubt you are. And even then, it would make more sense to find a solution that already exists.  Building a webserver is very involved, and you will unquestionably introduce bugs into it.